# Having issues with DataSet

Tags: dataset, dataframe, data-table

I just started learning data science and am having a problem when generating a dataset.

Dataset:

```
covid_data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Test\OneDrive\Desktop\Project_test\data.csv")
```

[image]

For some reason when I try to create a new dataset it creates an additional column "cases)" and adds NaN values automatically.

[image]

It happens randomly, it works for a while and when I restarted my jupyter notebook then it happened again. Any idea how to prevent this issue?

I obtain the dataset from https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/csv/data.csv

Screenshot of the data.csv file:
[image]

Comment: Can you also post some of the actual rows from data.csv here?

Answer (score 1):

I afraid I couldn't reproduce the same behavior on my machine.

[image]

I suggest the following:

- Check for `covid_data.columns` - As seen in my screenshot, please verify the columns the DataFrame reads.
- Provide the rest of your Jupyter notebook.
- You already tried restarting your notebook, but please verify you indeed restart the iPython Kernel. please do so by clicking the restart button or using the Kernel pane. In many cases this might do the trick.

[image]